# Swift enum with associated values

Tags: swift, enums

So far I've been using the rawValue to obtain the text according to the case like in this example:

```
enum Level1: String {
    case question1 = "q1"
    case question2 = "q2"
    case question3 = "q3"
}

print(Level1.question1.rawValue)
```

But now I would like to have the answers too. I tried to make it work with associated values but I don't know neither how to assign the value to the properties or even if it's possible. For example: questionText = "q1", answerText = "a1".

```
enum Level2 {
    case question1(questionText: String, answerText: String);
    case question2(questionText: String, answerText: String);
    case question3(questionText: String, answerText: String);
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think I found the answer I was looking for. I'll post below the code I'm going to use applied to the example used. Thanks for your answers.

```
    enum Level1: String {
    case question1 = "q1";
    case question2 = "q2";
    case question3 = "q3";

    init() {
        self = Level1.question1
    }

    func answer() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .question1:
            return "a1"
        case .question2:
            return "a2"
        case . question3:
            return "a3"
        }
    }
}

var currentLevel: Level1 = Level1();
print(currentLevel.rawValue);  //returns "q1"
print(currentLevel.answer());  //returns "a1"
```

Comment: but you have to code the same structure for every level.

Answer (score 3):

Enums with associated values cannot be type of string. But they can implement e.g. CustomStringConvertible protocol:

```
enum ScreenName: CustomStringConvertible {

    case Category(categoryId: String, categoryName: String)
    ...

    var description: String {
        switch (self) {
        case let .Category(_, categoryName):
            return "Category - \(categoryName)"
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

So then you can call `ScreenName.Category(categoryId: "1", categoryName: "products").description` and you will get `"Category - products"`

Comment: I need to access to both items separately to the already selected enum case. Like for example: ScreenName.categoryName and ScreenName.categoryId

Comment: I just found a better answer which I posted here. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: You can have as much computed variables as you wish (e.g. for name and for id)...

Answer (score 2):

You use the enums with associated values in the following way:

```
enum Level2 {
    case question1(questionText: String, answerText: String)
    case question2(questionText: String, answerText: String)
    case question3(questionText: String, answerText: String)
}

// initialise
let level = Level2.question2(questionText: "Question", answerText: "Answer")

// read

switch level {
case .question1(let question, let answer):
    print(question + answer)
case .question2(let question, let answer):
    print("something")
case .question3(let question, let answer):
    print("something else")
}
```

I would suggest to read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html

P.S: I would suggest to rethink if you really need to use enums in your case and not structs.
An example with using structs is:

```
struct Level {
    let question: String
    let answer: String
}

let levels = [Level]()
```

But this is another topic. I hope I have answered your question.

Comment: I know what you're trying to show me, but how do you store a different "Question" and "Answer" for each case? There you only assign to the second

Comment: I just found a better answer which I posted here. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Associated values are not like `RawRepresentable`(your first enum) in that its values are assigned at runtime, and can differ for each use. And basically, enums with associated values are not suitable for your needs.

Try this:

```
struct Challenge {

    let question: String
    let answer: String?
}

struct Level1 {

    static let challenge1 = Challenge(question: "q1", answer: nil)
    static let challenge2 = Challenge(question: "q2", answer: nil)
    static let challenge3 = Challenge(question: "q3", answer: nil)
}

struct Level2 {

    static let challenge1 = Challenge(question: "q1", answer: "a1")
    static let challenge2 = Challenge(question: "q2", answer: "a3")
    static let challenge3 = Challenge(question: "q3", answer: "a3")
}
```

Later you can retrive them:

```
let currentChallenge = Level1.challenge2
```

Comment: I understand and like your approach but I need something working with an enum because I'm all time checking the enum status. I know in this case would be easier to use this but the questions/answers are just an example to represent the situation not the real code.

Comment: implement `Equatable`, then you can check its equality with your state.

Comment: I just found a better answer which I posted here. Thanks a lot for your time.